# How can I recover my phone (factory reset doesn't work)?

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, data-recovery, 4.3-jelly-bean, asus-zenfone-5

My phone is Asus Zenfone 5 and I want to recover my phone but I can't because it always stucks in the screen with the Asus logo.

I've tried recovering it by using the factory data reset in the settings and a hard reset but it just stucks on the Asus logo.

I also have heard about recovering it on a computer but I couldn't find the link to download a suitable recovery version for my phone.

Notes:

- I use Android 4.3.
- My phone version is:

  > `ASUS_T00J_WW_user_1.15.40.35_20140715_3835release-keys 010175_201401130121`

Answer (score 2):

Get factory firmware [here](https://www.asus.com/Phone/ZenFone_5_A500CG/helpdesk_download/). There are versions matching exactly what you have (scroll down below), though ideally you need the one that also matches your SKU (region). It should come with instruction and tools (I can't verify), report back if not.